# xmpp javascript File transfer issue

Tags: javascript, mobile, xmpp, strophe

I am developing XMPP javascript application for web. I'm able to do text messaging. I want to do file transfer using strophe file transfer library. I send image file from  user1 to user2. The user2 is getting file, but the problem is how to download from strophe file transfer library.
I attached file handler `conn.si_filetransfer.addFileHandler(fileHandler);`
I attached

```
 conn.si_filetransfer.send(reskp,sid,filename, sizefile,'image/jpeg', function (err) {

 });
```

In  strophe.si-filetransfer.js file, it is calling receive and success function.

The problem is I am not able to read stanza content from success function. Could any one guide me?

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this could help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526701/save-received-files-from-xmpp-strophe-si-filetransfer

Comment: Thank you. I did like above previously .i got it.