# Save received files from xmpp Strophe si-filetransfer

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmpp, strophe

I am implementing file transfer in my web application using strophe.si-filetransfer.js plugin. I am able to receive file details within an iq stanza. My question is, How can I extract file data from an iq stanza and download it?

The link I referred to work around: https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/ibb

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

On the receiver side, you need to collect file info on **fileHandler** function, then grab all data chuncks on **ibbHandler** (e.g. using an array) and finally you have to join all file parts (data chuncks) and restore the original file.
In the example below (adapted from the link you suggest) I assume the file is chuncked using the FileReader API and [readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) method, so data are **base64** encoded.

```
var aFileParts, filename, mimeFile;

var fileHandler = function(from, sid, filename, size, mime) {
    // received a stream initiation
    filename = filename;
    mimeFile = mime;
};
connection.si_filetransfer.addFileHandler(fileHandler);

var ibbHandler = function (type, from, sid, data, seq) {
    switch(type) {
    case "open":
      // new file, only metadata
      aFileParts = [];
      break;
    case "data":
      // data
      aFileParts.push(data);
      break;
    case "close":
      // and we're done
      var data = "data:"+mimeFile+";base64,";
      for (var i = 0; i < aFileParts.length; i++) { 
         data += aFileParts[i].split(",")[1];
      }
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      span.innerHTML = '<a href="'+data+'" download="'+filename+'">'+filename+</a>;
    default:
      throw new Error("shouldn't be here.")
  }
};
```

Comment: New improved and complete answere here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292181/complete-example-of-strophe-js-file-transfer/35358428#35358428