# Complete example of Strophe.js file transfer

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe

I'm developing a chat web client (XMPP based) using Strophe.js. On server side I have an Openfire server.

I'm looking for a complete (and working) example of file transfer ([xep-0096](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html)) using Strophe.js.

I know there is a plugin, named **si-filetransfer**, which should help in implementing this feature but documentation is missing. So it is not easy to understand how it works.

Here on StackOverflow I found only some incomplete post relating the matter, as for example: [Save received files from xmpp Strophe si-filetransfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526701/save-received-files-from-xmpp-strophe-si-filetransfer)

Also on the web I didn't find any complete solution to my needs.

If there is another solution to achieve the above goal (file transfer in a JS client using XMPP protocol) it 's welcome!

Comment: `I found only some incomplete post relating the matter` - where? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526701/save-received-files-from-xmpp-strophe-si-filetransfer)?

Comment: Yes, it's one of them

Comment: @all_who_voted_to_close: I don't understand how could you evaluate my post as off-topic if 4 of you (4/5) do not have in their profile XMPP or Strophe...(and the last one does not have Strophe...).

Comment: thanks for your NON response

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here below is a very simple chat demo written using **jQuery** and **[StropheJS](http://strophe.im/strophejs/)** with **file transfer** features. Implementation of file transfer is based on these two Strophe.js plugins:

- https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/si-filetransfer: it allows to send and receive stream initiations
- https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/ibb. it provides a transport mechanism (In-Band Bytestream)

In addition, in order to allow the transfer of files greater than 65535 bytes it is also used a chunking algorithm.

Here is the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fYpXo1mFRWPxrLlgr123

P.S.: you have to deploy your own XMPP server and adapt the following code lines according to your configuration:

```
var server = 'mydomain.com';
var BOSH_SERVICE = 'http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind/';
```

Comment: I've tried your code and I noticed that occasionally it happens that ibb goes into timeout... Is there a solution for this issue?

Comment: You may use a more reliable connection changing from Http-bind (bosh) to Websockets, provided your server allows it. Obviously you have to change the connection url accordingly (i.e. ws://127.0.0.1:7070/ws/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @beaver!

Comment: @beaver   $('#btnSendFile').bind('click', function() {
 console.log('File clicked:');
 sendFileClick();
  }); is missing. and does not work.

Comment: @user914425 thanks, plunker updated

Comment: @beaver I am getting fileTransferHandler: err=Error: [object Element] error.  You also need to call handleFileSelect.  It is missing where it sets file object.

Comment: @beaver I am getting ibb.open: err=Error: feature-not-implemented in function fileTransferHandler(file,err)? What does this mean?

Comment: @user914425 maybe your server doesn't support IBB (check http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0047.html#create)

Comment: @beaver I am using the latest openfire 4.0.1.  Instead of In-Band Bytestreams how about  Out-of-Band Data.  How do I make the code changes?

Comment: @beaver can you also update the example to contain receiving files via both in band and out-of-band data?

Comment: @beaver can you post a working example for out-of-band file transfer based on https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/si-filetransfer?

Comment: @vp-platform I also notice ibb sometimes goes into timeout and when succeed always file is zero size.

Comment: @user914425 can you please say in details, how did you solve the error with err=Error: [object Element] error, cause I have this error now.  Thank you in advance

Comment: @beaver, or may be you know, how to solve this error. Thanks

Comment: @BohdanZ can you send me code where you getting the err=Error: [object Element]? As I mentioned above I am constantly getting timeout error and when it succeeded I get a zero size file.  See if you can implement out-of-band data transfer.  You will have better luck here.

Comment: @BohdanZ you might want to use this https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/blob/master/outofband/strophe.outofband.js. as a starting point.