# XMPP File Transfer via JavaScript Strophe.js in Openfire

Tags: javascript, html, xmpp, openfire, strophe.js

I am trying to get Strophe.js based XMPP file transfer to work. I can get logged in to work on my openfire server. I can send messages and receive messages fine but I am having trouble with file transfer.

HTML:

```
  <form name='file_form' class="panel-body">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" />
    <input type='button' id='btnSendFile' value='sendFile' />
    <output id="list"></output>
  </form>
```

Javascript file:

```
// file
var sid = null;
var chunksize;
var data; 
var file = null;
var aFileParts, mimeFile, fileName;


function sendFileClick() {
file =$("#file")[0].files[0];
sendFile(file);

readAll(file, function(data) {
    log("handleFileSelect:");
    log("   >data="+data);
    log("   >data.len="+data.length);
});
}

function sendFile(file) {
var to = $('#to').get(0).value;
var filename = file.name;
var filesize = file.size;
var mime = file.type;
chunksize = filesize;
sid = connection._proto.sid;
log('sendFile: to=' + to);
// send a stream initiation
connection.si_filetransfer.send(to, sid, filename, filesize, mime, function(err) {
    fileTransferHandler(file, err);
 });
}

function fileTransferHandler(file, err) {
log("fileTransferHandler: err=" + err);
if (err) {
return console.log(err);
}
var to = $('#to').get(0).value;
chunksize = file.size;

chunksize = 20 * 1024;

// successfully initiated the transfer, now open the band
connection.ibb.open(to, sid, chunksize, function(err) {
log("ibb.open: err=" + err);
if (err) {
  return console.log(err);
}


readChunks(file, function(data, seq) {
  sendData(to, seq, data);
});
});
}

function readAll(file, cb) {
var reader = new FileReader();

// If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
    cb(evt.target.result);
  }
};

reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function readChunks(file, callback) {
var fileSize = file.size;
var chunkSize = 20 * 1024; // bytes
var offset = 0;
var block = null;
var seq = 0;

 var foo = function(evt) {
   if (evt.target.error === null) {
    offset += chunkSize; //evt.target.result.length;
    seq++;
    callback(evt.target.result, seq); // callback for handling read chunk
   } else {
    console.log("Read error: " + evt.target.error);
    return;
   }
  if (offset >= fileSize) {
  console.log("Done reading file");
  return;
  }

  block(offset, chunkSize, file);
  }

  block = function(_offset, length, _file) {
  log("_block: length=" + length + ", _offset=" + _offset);
  var r = new FileReader();
  var blob = _file.slice(_offset, length + _offset);
  r.onload = foo;
  r.readAsDataURL(blob);
 }

  block(offset, chunkSize, file);
  }

   function sendData(to, seq, data) {
   // stream is open, start sending chunks of data
   connection.ibb.data(to, sid, seq, data, function(err) {
   log("ibb.data: err=" + err);
   if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
   }
   // ... repeat calling data
   // keep sending until you're ready you've reached the end of the file
  connection.ibb.close(to, sid, function(err) {
  log("ibb.close: err=" + err);
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  // done
 });
});
}



$('#btnSendFile').bind('click', function() {
console.log('File clicked:');
sendFileClick();
});
```

Full code is based on:
[Complete example of Strophe.js file transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292181/complete-example-of-strophe-js-file-transfer/35358428#35358428)
http://plnkr.co/edit/fYpXo1mFRWPxrLlgr123 (source can be download here: has errors).  I changed the sendFileClick function.
I am getting:

ibb.open: err=Error: feature-not-implemented?  Why is this error I am getting?

Comment: Did you use full JID (user@domain/resource) for sender?

Comment: @beaver I used full JID user@domain/resource.  The messages works just not the file.

Comment: @beaver I notice text message will only send if JID is user@domain or user@domain/Smack anything else will not deliver.

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem? It would be really nice to have a solution. Thanks

Comment: @BohdanZ the Strophe.js sample code does not use In of Band file transfer... that is why it is failing to send file.  My Javascript and XMPP knowledged is very limited to fully implement it on it is own.  Use this inband script and customize for this https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/ibb.  Post In-Band file transfer code of beaver 's script if you can. Let me know.