# XMPP: Possible to send media over bosh (http-bind)?

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe, converse.js

I found similar questions but the most of them are very old and in relation to XMPP (XEP-0231). In my case I was trying to do this only via bosh (http-bind) without a rich client and port 5222. I couldn't find anything in that direction. I've seen that the JSXC webclient can send images with a preview but I couldn't find any explanation for it. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Have you checked my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292181/complete-example-of-strophe-js-file-transfer/35358428#35358428?

Comment: Hello beaver :) Thx for the hint, i will try that. But especially I searching for a solution like whatsapp or google or facebook have. So that I can see the preview in a chat. It is impossible to find.

Comment: But what you are looking for is not part of XMPP. Only media/file transfer is related to XMPP protocol. You can reach the goal to preview media files in 
a chat using different web techniques.

Comment: hey beaver. thank you for your help. Since a few weeks I'm searching for a similar solution. I'm not so familiar with all these kinds of programming languages. I've tried candy chat with plugins (inline-images & videos) which perfectly adequate. Also JSXC has this features but I can't convert something else to converse.js with my knowledge. If you have an idea please let me know :)